# how to fix error maximum request length exceeded on mvc 5

Tags: web-config

I basically had an mvc5 FileUpload control, when i upload image over 4mb or it's error,my message:
Maximum request length exceeded.i had tried many another config on web.config but it's still same error
[click to see my web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u091k.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i had solved it,in my sulotion has 2 file web.config,i config file web.config in Views folder so it's wrong.i try config in original fodel and it's ok.